# Open popup from another popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I am trying to open a popup window from another popup window using window.open method but it is simply opening the second popup in the previous popup window.

Code I am currently using:

```
win= window.open(Window,"child","top=250,left=310,Width=300,Height=150,Location=no,Scrollbars=no") win.focus();
```

Comment: @Banang - check out the tags.

Comment: Popup hell is so nineties... :-)

Comment: @nfechner - Poppy like it's 1999?

Comment: I am using :
    win= window.open(Window,"child","top=250,left=310,Width=300,Height=150,Location=no,Scrollbars=no")
    win.focus();

Comment: I smell.... evil.  And biscuits (morning here, sorry).

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you're using a new name for your second new window. If you provide the same name you'll experience this behavior.

```
open(URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])
```

Comment: I am using : win= window.open(Window,"child","top=250,left=310,Width=300,Height=150,Location=no,Scrollbars=no") 
win.focus();

Comment: you'll need to give the second window a new name. Try win=window.open(Window, "child2", ....) win.focus(); You may also try name it _blank since that is the default standard for browsers to open a new window.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not care what the name of the window is instead of "child" use "_blank" which will always open in a new window. [see W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)